# onkeyUp and onChange are not working

Tags: html

```
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<!-- strat-contact-form --> 
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function checkMobileNumber(){
    alert("function");
    var phone = document.getElementbyId('phonenumber').value;
    console.log("resp: "+phone);
    var bool = isNaN(phone);
    if(!bool)
        document.getElementbyId.innerHTML = "Enter valid Mobile Number";
    }
};
</script>
<div class="contact-form">
<!-- start-form -->
    <form class="contact_form" action="RegistrationServlet" method="post" name="contact_form">
        <h1>Sign Up for New Account</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="email" class="textbox1" name="email" placeholder="info@resumeBuilder.com" required />
                <span class="form_hint">Enter a valid email</span>
                 <p><img src="images/contact.png" alt=""></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="password" name="website" class="textbox2" placeholder="password" required />
                <p><img src="images/lock.png" alt=""></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" class="textbox1" id = "phonenumber" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" onkeyup="checkMobileNumber()" onchange="checkMobileNumber()" required/>
                <span class="form_hint">Enter your Mobile Number</span>
                <span class="form_hint_error" id = "error"></span>
            </li>
         </ul>
            <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" value="Sign Up"/>
            <div class="clear"></div>   
        <div class="clear"></div>   
    </form>
<!-- end-form -->
<div class="clear"></div>       
</div>
<!-- end-contact-form -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run this OnkeyUp and onchange are not working when I'm trying this and alert didn't work from this I understand that the function itself is not being called please someone help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. syntax error: getElement**By**Id - the By should be upper case
2. syntax & logic error: if(!bool) **{** - missing **{**, isNaN means "is not a number"
3. syntax error:
   document.getElementbyId.innerHTML = "Enter valid Mobile Number";

```js
function checkMobileNumber(){
    alert("function");
    var phone = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value;
    console.log("resp: "+phone);
    var bool = isNaN(phone);
    if(bool){
        alert("Enter valid Mobile Number");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">
<!-- start-form -->
    <form class="contact_form" action="RegistrationServlet" method="post" name="contact_form">
        <h1>Sign Up for New Account</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="email" class="textbox1" name="email" placeholder="info@resumeBuilder.com" required />
                <span class="form_hint">Enter a valid email</span>
                 <p><img src="images/contact.png" alt=""></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="password" name="website" class="textbox2" placeholder="password" required />
                <p><img src="images/lock.png" alt=""></p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="text" class="textbox1" id = "phonenumber" name="phonenumber" placeholder="Mobile Number" onkeyup="checkMobileNumber()" onchange="checkMobileNumber()" required/>
                <span class="form_hint">Enter your Mobile Number</span>
                <span class="form_hint_error" id = "error"></span>
            </li>
         </ul>
            <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" value="Sign Up"/>
            <div class="clear"></div>   
        <div class="clear"></div>   
    </form>
<!-- end-form -->
<div class="clear"></div>       
</div>
<!-- end-contact-form -->
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance you're missing the open curly bracket for the if block in checkMobileNumber function. So the line:
`if(!bool)`
should be
`if(!bool) {`.